# Stop a user from COPY&PASTING url bypassing Login.asp?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have 2 pages

```
/login.asp
/menu.asp
```

I want to make it so the user has to login to view `/menu.asp`.

But as of now a user can just copy and paste `/menu.asp` and enter it without first logging in.

How would I make it so if the user enters `/menu.asp` without first logging in, it forces them to go back to the `/login` screen?

Comment: Are you asking more about how to make sure they're logged in, or how to programmatically execute the redirect?

Answer (score 3):

In the normal classic asp way I would expect:

1. you are setting a session variable (e.g. sesssion("loginsucceeded") = true)in you login.asp .
2. You check that session variable on all other pages and redirect to login.asp if not logged in.

Like this:

```
if (not session("loginsucceeded") = true) then 
    response.redirect login.asp : 
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many options in a few broad categories.

The simplest is probably to set a browser cookie in menu.asp once login is successful.  Then read that cookie in menu.asp (and any other page you want restricted), and if it's not there, just do a META or JS redirect to the login page.  You can set the cookie to expire if you want to.

The security of this is terrible (a user can edit his own cookies if he tries hard enough) but it'll probably work for prototyping.  A more secure system would involve issuing tokens instead of a static cookie, and checking if the token is valid on the server side.